# Socket Connection Pooling

Tags: java, sockets

The server is multi-threaded, Instead of creating a socket connection for each request, i want to maintain a pool of socket connections ? If one client has done with its work, then i want to restore the connection and use for another client, Could someone explain me how to do pool of socket connections ?

Comment: Sockets don't work like that; you can't share a socket connection between different clients.

Comment: Do you mean a thread for each client? That's what you should be asking for

Comment: @thedayofcondor .. Thanks for the comment!
Actually I have to develop a client Socket which connects to server socket at remote, the server socket has a Login command to access and hearbeat to maintain the session, now my Question actually is like, i have to go's
1) connect to socket-> Login ->process my command ->logout->client socket closed.
2) Once in lifetime till my app Up Connect to server->login-> maintain session using heartbeat-> process commands whenever request comes, till my app running

Comment: @AnilKumarAK Your 'actual' question has little or nothing to do with your original question, and indeed it isn't a question at all, just a statement of requirements. What *is* your 'actual' question'?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your trying to be build but if its TCP server than you should look at either one of these:

- Netty
- Grizzly
- Mina

Most of the above handles the thread pooling and long live connections for you (I have no idea what you mean by socket pooling). I highly recommend you don't re-implement the wheel till you look at some good wheels ;).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually I have to develop a client Socket which connects to server socket at remote, the server socket has a Login command to access and hearbeat to maintain the session, now my Question actually is like, i have to go's 1) connect to socket-> Login ->process my command ->logout->client socket closed. 2) Once in lifetime till my app Up Connect to server->login-> maintain session using heartbeat-> process commands whenever request comes, till my app running

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense. Inbound connections are *delivered* to you as new sockets, by the accept() function. You don't get any opportunity to pool them.

Answer (score 0):

It’s entirely up to the client and how it’s coded. The client should open a socket, and push multiple transactions through on that socket. Not much you can do from the server to enforce this, nor do I think it’s a good try to.

Regards
Yusuf