# Timeout mechanism with changeable usage time

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to implement mechanism which will be closing connections if there are not used by specific period of time. This time is constant for all of the connections. Opened connections can be used many times, so I need to update usage time and always compute difference between current time and usage time. I also need to close connections which excess my timeout.

My opened connections are in Map. (`Map<Id, Connection>`) where `Id` is an `Integer`.

I thought about resolving my problem with `DelayQueue`, but there is no possible to update usage (in this case delay) time in this type of `Queue`.

I also know that this mechanism should work in separate thread.

Please, give me some tip about the best way of implementation or example. What kind of data structure should I use? 
I can use Spring also (maybe there is some good mechanism and I don't know about it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking about database connectivity then just use connection poolers such as [c3po](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/), [hikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/), [BoneCP](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp) and so on. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about database. This is connections between two stacks in telecomunication area.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242311/socket-connection-pooling

Comment: It's not. I am not looking for TCP connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the HikariCP code.  Specifically, look at:

- [ConcurrentBag](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-common/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/util/ConcurrentBag.java)
- [PoolBagEntry](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-common/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBagEntry.java)
- [BaseDataSource.getConnection()](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-common/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/BaseHikariPool.java)
- [BaseDataSource.releaseConnection()](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-common/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/BaseHikariPool.java)
- [HouseKeeper](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.3.x/hikaricp-java6/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java) inner class

While HikariCP is a database connection pool, you can use ConcurrentBag as is, use the HouseKeeper basically as is, slightly modify PoolBagEntry, and lift the basic gist from getConnection() and releaseConnection(), to create a generic pool.